# ¿Como puedo manejar el envío de un objeto en un formulario al servidor con Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, array, nodejs, objeto

espero me puedan ayudar con mi duda, estoy trabajando por puro gusto con un sitio en el cual envio por un formulario un Objeto, lo que quiero hacer es recibirlo en una ruta especial pero al momento de recibir las variables del body me imprime solo **[object Object]** y ya he tratado de todo, con el **JSON.stringify(), Object.values**, incluso guardarlo separado como objeto pero me sigue mandando que su contenido es [object Object] como si el verdadero objeto fuera esa cadena, aqui mi formulario ejemplo:

```
<form action="/pokemon/add" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="idPoke" class="form-control" value="{{poke.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{poke.name}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="image" class="form-control" value="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/{{poke.id}}.png">
        <input type="hidden" name="types" class="form-control" value="{{poke.types}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="weight" class="form-control" value="{{poke.weight}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="height" class="form-control" value="{{poke.height}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="abilities" class="form-control" value="{{poke.abilities}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="stats" class="form-control" value="{{poke.stats}}">
      <a href="/pokemon/all" class="btn btn-success">
        Cerrar
      </a>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info ">
        Agregar a mi pokedex!
      </button>
```

**los names que están en plural son objetos que consumo desde una api en esa vista**

código del servidor:

```
router.post('/pokemon/add', async (req,res) => {
    const {idPoke, name, image, types, weight, height, abilities, stats} = req.body;
    console.log(types); //el error aqui incluso con stringify, each, etc
    // const newPokemon= new Pokemon({idPoke, name, image, types, weight, height, abilities, stats});
    // await newPokemon.save();
    //res.redirect('/pokemon/my-pokes');
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a darme cuenta en que estoy mal, soy muy nuevo en nodejs y la verdad no encuentro como obtener el objeto para guardarlo como un objeto en mi base de datos MongoDB

*EDIT:* Para front estoy utilizando un motor de plantillas de express-handlebars

Comment: Que estás usando para el Front? Y si estás usando express, la otra pregunta sería:  estas usando en el server el Middleware express.urlencoded()?, Seria algo como: app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

Comment: @LuisS.Romero estoy utilizando express-handlebars y si tengo esa linea que me comentas en mis middlewares, gracias por tu comentario amigo:)

Comment: En dónde estás pondeniendo el `JSON.stringify()`? Sería bueno revisaras el tipo de req.body también